# How to determine when a command is going to fall on the host and print output for the user?

Tags: powershell

I have this small search utility, [ES Cli](https://www.voidtools.com/support/everything/command_line_interface/), that I have managed to wrap into a PowerShell function.

While I have managed to figure out most things, I am stuck on handling its output, so that it works with PowerShell.

I need to get the function to output two kinds of output, if the function is going to fall on the host directly and its output printed, I would like `test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes` to output:

```
1.75 KB     D    C:\dogs
347  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs 3.png
446  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs-man.png
562  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs 1.png
446  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs 2.png
```

Otherwise, I would like the function to output plain paths:

```
C:\dogs
C:\dogs\dogs 3.png
C:\dogs\dogs-man.png
C:\dogs\dogs 1.png
C:\dogs\dogs 2.png
```

Ignoring `-Properties Size,Extension,Attributes` regardless of them being present. This way use cases such as:

- `$var = test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes`
- `test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes|Get-ChildItem`
- `Get-ChildItem -path (test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes)`
  result in valid file paths being received.

I did manage to get it to partly work, `test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes|get-item |% fullname`:

```
C:\dogs
C:\dogs\dogs 3.png
C:\dogs\dogs-man.png
C:\dogs\dogs 1.png
C:\dogs\dogs 2.png
```

But doing something like `$var = test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes` stores:

```
1.75 KB     D    C:\dogs
347  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs 3.png
446  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs-man.png
562  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs 1.png
446  B png  A    C:\dogs\dogs 2.png
```

And doing `get-item (test -Search 'c:\dogs dog' -Limit 5 -Properties Size,Extension,Attributes)` results:

```
Get-Item: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '       1.75 KB      D    C' does not exist.
```

I have been searching around and coming up with more convoluted solutions but I cant quite address all cases. I would appreciate any help.

The function is:

```
function test{
param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string]$Search,
    [string]$Limit = 1,

    [ArgumentCompletions('Name','Path','NameAndPath','Filename','Extension','Size','DateCreated','DateModified','DateAccessed','Attributes','FileList','RunCount','Daterun','DateRecentlyChanged')]
    [string[]]$Properties = ('size', 'DateModified'),

    [ArgumentCompletions('CaseSensitive', 'WholeWord', 'MatchPath')]
    [string[]]$Options = 'MatchPath',

    [ArgumentCompletions('Name','Path','Size','Extension','DateCreated','DateModified','DateAccessed','Attributes','FileList','RunCount','DateRecentlyChanged','DateRun')]
    [string[]]$Sort = 'DateModified',

    [switch]$Ommit,
    [switch]$Descending
)
    $Options = switch -Regex ($Options){
        'CaseSensitive|case'    {'-case'}
        'WholeWord|ww'          {'-whole-word'}
        'MatchPath|mp'          {'-match-path'}
        }
    $Sort = switch ($Sort){
        'Name'                      {'-sort-name'}
        'Path'                      {'-sort-path'}
        'Size'                      {'-sort-size'}
        'Extension'                 {'-sort-extension'}
        'DateCreated'               {'-sort-date-created'}
        'DateModified'              {'-sort-date-modified'}
        'DateAccessed'              {'-sort-date-accessed'}
        'Attributes'                {'-sort-attributes'}
        'FileList'                  {'-sort-file-list-file-name'}
        'RunCount'                  {'-sort-run-count'}
        'DateRecentlyChanged'   {'-sort-date-recently-changed'}
        'DateRun'                   {'-sort-date-run'}
        }
    $Pretify =  @(If ($MyInvocation.pipelineLength -gt 1){'-full-path-and-name'}                #Part of the pipeline
                    else{
                            switch ($Properties){
                                'Name'                      {'-name'}
                                'Path'                      {'-path-column'}
                                'NameAndPath'               {'-full-path-and-name'}
                                'Filename'                  {'-filename-column'}
                                'Extension'                 {'-extension'}
                                'Size'                      {'-size'}
                                'DateCreated'               {'-date-created'}
                                'DateModified'              {'-date-modified'}
                                'DateAccessed'              {'-date-accessed'}
                                'Attributes'                {'-attributes'}
                                'FileList'                  {'-file-list-file-name'}
                                'RunCount'                  {'-run-count'}
                                'Daterun'                   {'-date-run'}
                                'DateRecentlyChanged'   {'-date-recently-changed'}
                                }
                                '-size-format',
                                'mb',
                                '-highlight',
                                '-highlight-color',
                                '0x02'
                            }
                    )
ESCommandLine @Pretify @sort @Options ($Descending ? '-sort-descending' : '-sort-ascending') -max-results @Limit $Search.Split(' ')  #$search has to be split, the native command requires it so
}
```

Comment: Can you please review the post? It’s not clear what you expect to happen on each case. It even seems that you already obtain the output you need.